# iconv can't convert circled numbers to/from Japanese encodings

Tags: character-encoding

The unicode range of circled digits (U+2460 .. U+2468) cannot be converted to, or from, any of the Japanese encodings (EUC-JP, Shift-JIS, ISO-2022-JP), [even though they exist there](http://chars.suikawiki.org/char/2460), and I run across them all the time.

```
% echo ①②③③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨ | iconv -f utf-8 -t euc-jp
iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert
% echo ①②③③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨ | iconv -f utf-8 -t shift-jis
iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert
% echo ①②③③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨ | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-2022-jp
iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert

% printf "\xad\xa1\xad\xa2\xad\xa3\xad\xa3 \xad\xa4\xad\xa5\xad\xa6\xad\xa7\xad\xa8\xad\xa9" | iconv -f euc-jp -t utf-8 
iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert
% printf "\x87\x40\x87\x41\x87\x42\x87\x42 \x87\x43\x87\x44\x87\x45\x87\x46\x87\x47\x87\x48" | iconv -f shift-jis -t utf-8 
iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3):

[Those characters actually do not exist in those three encodings.](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-libiconv/2009-11/msg00001.html) You actually want `EUC-JIS-2004` aka `EUC-JISX0213` instead of plain EUC-JP, `SHIFT_JIS-2004` or `CP932` instead of SHIFT_JIS, and `ISO-2022-JP-2004` instead of plain ISO-2022-JP.

```
% printf "\xad\xa1\xad\xa2\xad\xa3 \xad\xa4\xad\xa5\xad\xa6\xad\xa7\xad\xa8\xad\xa9" | iconv -f euc-jisx0213 -t utf-8 
①②③ ④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨
```